# Can I scroll the windows in emacs synchronously?

Tags: emacs

I mean if I type in c-x 2, then for comparasion I want it to scroll the other window synchronously when I scroll the temporary window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Follow Mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html):

```
M-x follow-mode
```

> *Follow mode* is a minor mode that makes two windows, both showing the same buffer, scroll as a single tall “virtual window”.

Note that *follow mode* can only synchronize scrolling windows which content a same file. For scrolling windows with diffrent files synchronously, [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WishList)'s an answer for it.

> Follow mode can only synchronize scrolling windows which content a
>   same file. Does it possible to scrolling windows with diffrent files
>   synchronously? – 9307420654
>
> There is a minor mode to apply all scrolling commands to all visible
>   windows in the current frame. Check [scroll-all-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollAllMode) for that. Or else,
>   if you want to scroll together only 2 windows and only when you use a
>   specific keystroke, you can do something like a function that scrolls
>   the current window (scroll-up or scroll-down) and then the “other
>   window” (i.e., the next one in the list of windows), with
>   scroll-other-window (with argument '-, i.e., the symbol “minus”, for
>   scrolling down). Then you can assign this to a keystroke, e.g., C-M-up
>   / down.

[scroll-all-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollAllMode):

> Use `M-x scroll-all-mode` to scroll multiple buffers together.
>
> Very useful for visually comparing two files which are hard to diff
>   because of lots of trivial changes amongst the changes you are looking
>   for.

Comment: Thank you.If I open two different file. it there any way to make it work too?

Comment: For example, I want to see two test.py, but they are not exactly the same, so I want to compare them.

Comment: @Crazymage Follow mode can only synchronize scrolling windows which content a same file. `scroll-all-mode` could apply all scrolling commands to all visible windows in the current frame. And see @ocasoprotal's answer.

Comment: Yes, scroll-all-mode works, there is only one flaw which is it doesn't work when scrolling with mouse wheel in windows.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution might be the [scroll-all-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollAllMode):

```
M-x scroll-all-mode
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, if the windows you want to compare are somehow similar (like different versions of the same file), you probably would like to use a "diff" tool, like `M-x ediff-buffers` which compares the buffers with colors and keeps them scrolling in sync.